# Create bitmap overlay with some information

Tags: android, bitmap, android-video-player

I've created a `Bitmap` [Thumbnail] which is fetched after picking a video from gallery.

Snippet:-

```
bm= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(currentFileUri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

I'm putting these bitmap in Gallery adapter which is meant from images only, tht's y i'm creating thumbnail of Video and putting there. But

*I want to show some difference between image and video in Gallery Strip which can be done by overlaying VideoThumbnail with something like Play Option.*

[image: Something like these]

Tried to OverLay my Bitmap with Small Play Icon but it throws  *NullPointerException* on `Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(..)`

Snippet:-

```
bm= ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(currentFileUri.getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
Bitmap change = null;
Bitmap border = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();
change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(change);
Bitmap scaledBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(border,width/2,height/2, false);
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBorder, 0, 0,null);
```

Adding that newly Overlay Created bitmap on my adapter.

```
AddIPDActivity.this.data.add(bm);
```

Comment: dont create scaled Bitmaps: its a waste of CPU and memory: use LayerDrawable for such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created Overlay `BitMap` with `LayerDrawable`

Bitmap on which overlay need to be done.

```
bm = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(currentFileUri.getPath(),MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

LayerDrawable applied on `Bitmap` with custom image on it.

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
```

Added Bitmap on Gallery - Adapter.

```
this.data.add(drawableToBitmap(geSingleDrawable(layerDrawable))); //data is adapter for Gallery.
```

Converting LayerDrawable into BitMap:-

LayerDrawable -> Drawable -> BitMap

```
  public static Drawable geSingleDrawable(LayerDrawable layerDrawable){
        int resourceBitmapHeight = 136, resourceBitmapWidth = 153;
        float widthInInches = 0.9f;
        int widthInPixels = (int)(widthInInches * SmartConsultant.getApplication().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
        int heightInPixels = widthInPixels * resourceBitmapHeight / resourceBitmapWidth;
        int insetLeft = 10, insetTop = 10, insetRight = 10, insetBottom = 10;
        layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);     
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthInPixels, heightInPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels);
        layerDrawable.draw(canvas);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(SmartConsultant.getApplication().getResources(), bitmap);
        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels);
        return bitmapDrawable;
}
    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: What is SmartConsultant?

Comment: @ManishaPatel Its just to get application context. One can use get context() or getBaseContext()

Answer (score 0):

u r getting `NPE` because

```
Bitmap change = null;
change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
```

`change is always null`. U r passing a `null value`.So, before passing `change` as a parameter of `createScaledBitmap(parameters)` assign a `bitmap` to `change` after that call this

```
change = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(change, width, height, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your acknowledgement. Your perfectly right on NPE. :)